# Attempt1: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.Attempt1: line 4, column 1

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product, pricebookentry

I'm getting the following error when I try to add a product to an opportunity. I am working on a trigger that would automatically add a productB whenever productA is added to the opportunity. Are you guys able to help me fix this code?

```
    trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
    for (OpportunityLineItem newOpportunityLineItems: Trigger.New) { 
        if(newOpportunityLineItems.name.equals('Car_Filter_Plus')){
            OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                                        OpportunityId = newOpportunityLineItems.OpportunityId, 
                                        PricebookEntryId ='01eA000000QdplcIAF',
                                        Quantity = 1,
                                        UnitPrice = 25)
                                    );
        }
    } 
    if(!OpportunityLineItems.isEmpty()){
        insert OpportunityLineItems; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use "equals" on an object reference, because it may be null:

```
    if(newOpportunityLineItems.name == 'Car_Filter_Plus') {
```

Secondly, this implies that name is probably null, so you might need to actually do a query first:

```
for(OpportunityLineItem item: [
   SELECT OpportunityId, Name 
   FROM OpportunityLineItem
   WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Name = 'Car_Filter_Plus']) {
        OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = item.OpportunityId, 
            PricebookEntryId ='01eA000000QdplcIAF',
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 25)
        );
}
```

Finally, you don't need to check if a list is empty before doing a DML:

```
// if(!OpportunityLineItems.isEmpty()){
    insert OpportunityLineItems; 
// }
```

Comment: I used the code that you provided and here id the error that it gave me:
"Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'OpporunityLineItem' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 3 column 31 "

Comment: @HUBBY0716 It was just a typo.

Comment: its Monday.. hehe... whats the typo? :)

Comment: nevermind. the code looks like worked, but the additional product didn't get added to the opportunity :(

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I thought this code would automatically add the 2nd product automatically once the 1st one gets added manually

Comment: @HUBBY0716 It should, but you might need to check the exact value of Name. It doesn't usually have underscores.

Comment: I changed to "Car Filter Plus". Still not adding... frustrating... :(